# Do cameras do lens correction for in camera JPEGs?

Tags: raw, darktable, lensfun

What are the steps involved when a camera converts RAW images into JPEG?

Based on the Lensfun database I believe the camera is at least doing some things that are on a per-lens-basis, such as fixing distortion / glass curvature, maybe correcting some chromatic aberration, removing dark vignetting on the edges of the photo, etc. Of course, the camera itself doesn't use Lensfun, but the manufacturer maintains its own database and delivers updates to cameras via firmware.

It also seems like there might be some slight cropping, and surely some adjustments of the colors overall, in addition to what Lensfun is doing.

I guess another way of looking at this is that when a camera saves RAW + JPEG images, it can do a pretty good job creating those JPGs. Is it ever really worth saving both formats or is it expected that one can perform every single one of those operations in post-production to the RAW to get the same quality JPG?

I'm using a Sony a7 II, darktable on Linux, and have updated my Lensfun database.

Comment: Welcome to Photo SE - I think you really have two questions here: "How does a camera convert RAW to JPEG?" and "Why would someone shoot RAW + JPEG?". Could you edit this to be about just one of those (and ask the other one in a separate question if you still want it)? Thanks.

Comment: The main part of the question seems to me to only be about one specific aspect of raw to JPEG conversion: what lens correction, if any, is applied.

Comment: The second half of this question has been asked/answered *ad nauseum* here. If asked separately, surely it would be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: I've closed this question until the OP clarifies which bit they want answered - at the moment we've got a bad mismatch between the title, the body of the question and the answers being given which isn't going to help anybody find the information they want.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part...

When you convert from Raw to JPEG, choices are made, and some data is lost.In particular the color channels are quantized to 256 values each (8 bits) while a raw file encodes 12 to 14 bits per channel and so has 4096 to 16384 values, and even if you go with the pessimistic/realistic 10-bits due to noise, that's still 1024 values.

So, if the JPEG from the camera is about right, that's fine, but if you need to compensate later for a wrong choice (exposure, color balance), you have much less to work with in a JPEG. And if you use aggressive settings (saturation, contrast, sharpening) in the camera, the resulting JPEGs become very hard to work with.

So, given the size of the SD cards and PC disks these days, using raw+jpeg is a very workable solution (unless you use  burst mode because this can reduce your burst rate) and lets you create jpegs with more "pop" without jeopardizing your ability to fix the image later if necessary.

But since you are on Linux, there is one thing that the in-camera JPEG has over the RAW: it can have the manufacturers own lens corrections applied (but then I have a faint memory of Sony being scolded because it did some of this to its raw files). And of course the in-camera JPEG won't correct off-brand lenses (Sigma, Tamron, Samyang...).

Comment: Technically, RAW does not have "12 to 14 bits per channel", though.... it's 12 to 14 bits per sensel, and the value is just an intensity value, although filtered by whichever color filter that particular sensel falls behind. There isn't really a concept of "per channel" until after demosaicing....

Comment: No camera currently outputs more than 8 bit color; even with the  raw file.

Answer (score 0):

There are far too many complexities/variables as to how a camera [demosaics a raw file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demosaicing) in order to create a jpeg; but yes, it may apply lens profiles which may include cropping. And it most certainly alters the colors based on a variety of settings.

The edits the camera applies cannot be undone; which makes them something of a compromise. As an example, do you set it so that you have the greatest chance of the best final image; i.e. light edits/"flat" picture style. Or do you set it so you have the best chance of the most ideal image, not requiring any edits in post; i.e. heavy edits/"vivid" picture style.

The main advantage of recording raw with your camera is in situations of high dynamic range. Your camera is nearly ISO invariant which means you can underexpose to save highlights and recover in post with little penalty. But if you were to do that with a jpeg it is likely that the data in the darker parts of the image would be lost (written as "black").
Your camera also has the ability to record slightly more (< 1 stop) total dynamic range than a jpeg can encode, which can be useful as "highlight recovery" when editing the raw file.

Recording both formats allows you to compromise the jpeg for certain images (e.g. not change the picture style, underexpose, etc) knowing you can edit the raw file to get the result you want (hopefully). And yes, if you knew what the jpeg edits were, and had the appropriate software, you can apply them the raw file and get exactly the same result. Some (most?) OEM software does this automatically (e.g. Nikon NX Studio).

The main negative of recording dual files is that it slows down the camera some. In my testing with Nikons the least penalty is raw + basic jpeg (the embedded jpeg), next is dual raw. Both of those do not require additional processing, but are also only really of benefit in an emergency situation (backup).

The worst is raw + highest quality jpeg, as that requires the most additional processing. But it is also most likely to give you the best jpeg for use without editing.

Answer (score 0):

> Based on the Lensfun database I believe the camera is at least doing some things that are on a per-lens-basis, such as fixing distortion / glass curvature, maybe correcting some chromatic aberration, removing dark vignetting on the edges of the photo, etc.

- Some cameras automatically apply lens corrections, such as for lens distortion and chromatic aberration, whether the user wants it to or not. That is, assuming a lens profile for that specific lens is available in the camera's database. This first became common with Micro Four Thirds cameras. This allowed the manufacturers to use lighter, simpler lens designs with fewer optical aberration corrections.
- Some cameras give the user the option of whether or not they want lens correction applied when the lens' profile is included in the camera's database. Sometimes the user must load a profile for a specific lens.
- Some cameras do not offer the capability to apply any lens correction to the in camera JPEGs produced from the raw data.